# Do Maxwell's equations conserve energy?

Tags: energy-conservation, maxwell-equations, poynting-vector

I was wondering if Maxwell equations conserved energy.
Jackson is not really convincing about the whole Poynting theorem (neither currently google found articles which just assume a bunch of stuff).

Does anyone have an insightful/intuitive explanation or should I just take it for granted?

Rotational field means the curl is different than $0$.
Conservative force needs $\nabla$x$\vec{F} = 0$
Is energy conserved?

Comment: What's not convincing about the Poynting theorem?

Comment: For a system of electrically charged matter in flat spacetime, the SET is conserved (i.e. $\partial_\mu \left(\Theta^{\mu\nu} (F) + T^{\mu\nu}_{\text{matter}}\right) = 0$, with $\Theta$ the symmetric Belinfante-Rosenfeld tensor).  Perhaps you can read the book by Barut on electrodynamics (Barut, A. - Electrodynamics and classical theory of fields and particles) for an alternate proof.

Comment: You don't need any assumptions beyond Maxwell's equations and the Lorentz force law.  Perhaps you could elaborate on what you find unsatisfactory.

Comment: I'm downvoting this question until clarification comes. It's really annoying when someone states that some derivation is not convincing and doesn't point out any problems. What do you expect to get as an answer?

Comment: I expected to get an answer considering why rotating fields in ME are considered conservative. A physical answer, rather than a mathematical derivation.

Answer (score 2):

Maxwell's equations are equivalent to the [Lagrangian for classical electrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism#Lagrangian_for_classical_electrodynamics). According to the [Noether theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem), energy is conserved, if the Lagrangian has a continuous symmetry of time transaltion, as it does. Thus Maxwell's equations do conserve energy.

Comment: Well, that depends whether the current field is dynamical or not. Usually in the Lagrangian framework of EM it's taken to be a background field, in which case if the charges are moving then the Lagrangian isn't time translationally invariant anymore, so conservation of energy isn't obvious. Making the current dynamical requires generalizing to Maxwell-Klein-Gordon theory or spinor electrodynamics, which I think is stretching the OP's question.

Comment: @tparker Yeah, The OP just wanted a simple intuitive explanation. In real cases, the math can be complicated, but physically we know that energy is conserved in electromagnetism. Therefore there must be a way to address any discrepancies by potential energy corrections, which may be a bit too deep for me :)

Comment: @tparker why going to matter fields? Can you not use the normal Lagrangian with dynamic electromagnetic field coupled to classical matter.

Comment: This is what I mean. You have a circular field, the rotation of the field is $!=$ $0$.    
If the rotation of the field is $!=$ $0$, the energy is not conserved.

Comment: @DominikCar Yeah, I'd say this answer is basically incorrect, because it ignores the EM field's back-reaction on the charges, and any full energy accounting that conserves energy would have to include the mechanical energy that the fields transfer to the charges.

Comment: @lalala By "classical matter", do you mean "background field manually specified at all times", or do you mean "point particles"? You can have classical matter fields in the form of continuum fluids, and in fact this is the much more natural way to think about it when you're doing field theory, because point particles have awkward issues with radiation backreaction and so on. If the charges are all point particles, then you're arguably better off working with Jefimenko's than with Maxwell's equations.

Comment: @tparker If you "include the mechanical energy that the fields transfer to the charges", then the Lagrangian of the system would have to include these charges as well and then the energy is still conserved. I am not sure what your objection is, do you doubt the energy conservation law? It applies to the whole system, so of course the Lagrangian must be of the whole system as well.

Comment: Yes, I agree that if the charges are fully dynamical and have kinetic energy terms in the Lagrangian, then energy will certainly be conserved. But typically "the Lagrangian for classical electrodynamics" doesn't include such a charge kinetic term, because that requires choosing a model for the charges (scalar field, spinor field, point particles, etc.), and different models are useful for different applications.